# Search scope item count is zero when content source has items

Tags: search-express, search, crawling, search-scope

I installed Search Server Express 2010 on a SharePoint Foundation farm.  It's a pretty basic install - I let the Local SharePoint sites crawler finish and it found about 200 items.  When I look at the All Sites scope, however, the item count is zero.  Even if I set the scope update to on-demand it doesn't seem to want to pick up items.  Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a policy applied in Active Directory that messed with default permissions.  [A post from the TechNet forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/688b5c52-f478-463b-bc00-debfd0c3be2b) pointed me in the right direction.